# how to properly call functions in prototype in js

Tags: javascript

How do I properly call the functions inside pretest?

I get this error: **Uncaught TypeError: b.testmenow is not a function**

```js
    var pretest = function () {
        var MAX_NUM = 250.0;
    
        var prebase = function (NEW_NUM) {
            this.NEW_NUM = NEW_NUM ? NEW_NUM : true;
        };
    
        prebase.prototype.testmenow = function () {
            return this.NEW_NUM;
        };
        
        return prebase;
    };
    
    var b = new pretest(111);
    console.log(b.testmenow());
```

Comment: Part of me says you need to `return new prebase()` but it's super strange how you're doing this. Try searching to learn more on [prototypes and constructors](https://hackernoon.com/prototypes-in-javascript-5bba2990e04b).

Comment: how do i fix the code?

Comment: `pretest` is a function that returns a constructor, it's not a constructor itself. Not sure why you are doing this, but with minimal changes to your code: `var b = new (pretest())(111);`.

Comment: Curious to know why you don't just use `prebase` directly — what is `pretest`'s contribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to accept your input into `new pretest(111)` by adding `n`.
And then you must instantiate your prebase constructor using n.

```js
    var pretest = function (n) {
        var MAX_NUM = 250.0;
    
        var prebase = function (NEW_NUM) {
            this.NEW_NUM = NEW_NUM ? NEW_NUM : true;
        };
    
        prebase.prototype.testmenow = function () {
            return this.NEW_NUM;
        };
        
        return new prebase(n);
    };
    
    var b = pretest(111);
    console.log(b.testmenow());
```

It is strange that you have two constructors here, you can surely do this with one.

As Felix has deftly mentioned, you can call `pretest(111)` instead of `new pretest(111)`.

Comment: There is no reason to call `pretest` with `new`. It's rather confusing. Just do `var b = pretest(111);`.

Comment: so If I have multiple parameters I need to return new prebase(n,x,y,z); ?